# What does 歩けというの mean in this song?

Tags: verbs, particle-と, song-lyrics, explanatory-の

In the song Cry by Garnidelia there're two lines that go:

> ひとり　どこへ
>
> 歩｛ある｝けというの

The second line is what I don't get. I've tried looking up というの but didn't see anything about it at the end of a sentence, and I don't understand why 歩｛ある｝け gets translated as walkING. There's an English translation of the song that translates these two lines as "Where am I heading, walking alone?"

I guess my specific questions are:

What's this ーえ form of 歩く supposed to mean in this context?

How does the verb relate to というの and what does というの even mean lol?

If that English translation is fine, then would changing the line to 歩いているの lose any nuance or meaning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

というの asks rhetorical questions (it's literally just と, 言う, and の). If your mom told you to keep studying for a long time you might say something like 死ぬまで勉強しろというのか "you want me to study until I die, is that it?!" Or, more literally "are you telling (言う) me to study until I die?!" As you can see it's a bit difficult to line up the tenses between the two languages, and that's okay.

In 一人どこへ歩けと言うの, without looking up the full song, seems like the speaker is talking to themself or an unspecified or imaginary person. more literally is "where are you telling me I should go, all alone?" Or "where am I supposed to go, all alone". There could be many different ways of wording this.

歩け is an imperative. 歩いているの would not work as a replacement. I think that fan translation is fine.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you